# Haskell: What's the type of this function?

Tags: haskell, ghc

```
mifun s = foldr op 0 s
          where op x r = head x + r
```

Is there a way to make ghci tell me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try `:t mifun` (short for `:type mifun`)

which gives

```
*Main> :t mifun
mifun :: (Num b) => [[b]] -> b
```

So, for a `b` an instance of `num`, `mifun` takes a list of lists of `b` and outputs a single `b` (which in this case is the sum of the first elements of the lists).

Answer (score 2):

*This isn't really an answer, but I needed the formatting.*

**N.B.:** `mifun` is ⊥ if any of the contained lists is empty. For example:

```
> mifun [[3], [5, 8], [], [1, 2, 3]]
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

If you want the result of the above example to be 9 (treating an empty list as not contributing to the sum), then you should define op as one of the following ways:

```
mifun s = foldr op 0 s
          where op []    r = r
                op (x:_) r = x + r 

mifun s = foldr op 0 s
          where op x r = (if null x then 0 else head x) + r 

mifun s = foldr op 0 s
          where op x r = sum (take 1 x) + r
```

I'd probably prefer the first.

Comment: Actually, if you define an instance of Num that is lazy enough, `mifun [[3::MyLazyNum], [5, 8], [], [1, 2, 3]] >= 8` could be evaluated to true without causing an exception, so it might be more accurate to say "The result of `mifun` *contains* ⊥ if any of the contained lists is empty".

Comment: True enough - I can think of even more instances with bizarre behavior in this case... However, given the focus of the original question, I'd bet they are working with standard Num instances, and I wanted to point out a potential pitfall of the function itself.